# Kotlin ktor client load javascript website

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

Hey so i want to request to a website but i get an error that „javascript is not enabled in this browser“ someone know how to request with javascript enabled?

Comment: Could you please describe how you make a request? What browser do you use?

Comment: Im not using a browser i want to us ethe ktor client for my request rn i use the engine CIO.